# Find id by comparing query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable `Names` which contains the following data:

```
SELECT * FROM Names
```

and its result:

```
Name
-----
Jon
Adam 
Ben
Joseph
```

In addition, there is a function `fn_GetNamesById(@Id)` which gets `Name` by `id`(1):

```
SELECT * FROM fn_GetColumns(1)
```

and its result would be:

```
Name
-----
Jon
Adam 
Ben
Joseph
```

another `id`(2) would return another result

```
SELECT * FROM fn_GetColumns(2)
```

and its result would be:

```
Name
-----
Adam 
Jon
Joseph
Ben
```

another `id`(3) would return another result:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_GetColumns(3)
```

and its result would be:

```
Name
-----
Marc
William 
Gordon
Wiktor
Felix
```

What I want is to find id  in `UDF/Stored procedure` named `Find_ID(@IDs, @Names)` by comparing result of table variable `Names` with result of function `fn_GetColumns(id)`.

The parameters of `Stored Procedure/UDF` are:

```
@IDs TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier) -- possible IDs (1,2,3, ...1000)
@Names TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier) -- desired names
```

To do this, I've written a `stored procedure Find_ID` which contains a loop `WHILE` **to iterate through IDs**. Current **id** will be put in function `fn_GetColumns(id)` and then the result of `fn_GetColumns(id)` will be compared with result table variable `@Names`.

However, I do not know how I can compare two query result and get current `id` if query result are the same:

```
-- My stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [Find_ID]   (
@IDs [UWQ].[TY_MyType] READONLY,
@Names [UWQ].[TY_MyNames] READONLY

DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier)
DECLARE @Names TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier)
DECLARE @Processed INT


DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @IDs)
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50);

--loop:
WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
BEGIN

    --we are iterating through id = 1, 2, 3
    SET @VALUE = (SELECT ID FROM
        (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) [index] , 
            ID from @IDs) R 
         ORDER BY R.[index] OFFSET @COUNTER 
         ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);

    // pseudo code: if  SELECT * FROM fn_GetColumns(1) is equal to SELECT * 
    // FROM Names THEN return @VALUE
    // pseudo code: else iterate to find id 
    // pseudo code: if there is no names then return NULL

    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END
```

Is it possible to find `id` of function `fn_GetColumns(id)` if query results are the same?

For example:

```
DECLARE @Names table 
(
    Names VARCHAR(50)
)
insert into @Names 
VALUES
    (Jon), (Adam) , (Ben), (Joseph)

DECLARE @Ids table 
(
    ID int
)
insert into @Ids 
VALUES
    (1),(2) , (3), (4)

EXEC Find_ID(@IDs, 
         @Names)
```

**OUTPUT: 1** -- as UDF `fn_GetColumns(1)` returns the same query result
                 like `SELECT * FROM Names`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can just count of query result of `EXCEPT` operator. If count of unique rows is 0, then it means that necessary `ID` is found:

```
 SELECT 
     @DesiredID = count(1) 
 FROM 
 (
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM @Names) InputNames
     EXCEPT
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 Name 
     FROM fn_GetColumns(@VALUE) ORDER BY ColumnOrder) DesiredNames
 ) rn

 IF @DesiredID = 0
 BEGIN
     PRINT @DesiredID
     PRINT @VALUE
     BREAK
 END
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID uniqueidentifier)
DECLARE @Processed INT
INSERT INTO @IDs
SELECT 
f.ID 
FROM Fields f
GROUP BY f.ID

DECLARE @Names TABLE
(
    Name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Names
VALUES
('Jon'), ('Adam'), ('Ben'), ('Joseph')



 DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
 DECLARE @MAX INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @IDs)
 DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50);
 DECLARE @DesiredID VARCHAR(50);

 WHILE @COUNTER < @MAX
 BEGIN

     SET @VALUE = (SELECT ID FROM
         (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) [index] , ID from @IDs) R 
          ORDER BY R.[index] OFFSET @COUNTER 
          ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY);

          --PRINT @VALUE
         SELECT 
             @DesiredID = count(1) 
         FROM 
         (
             SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM @Names) InputNames
             EXCEPT
             SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 Name 
             FROM fn_GetColumns(@VALUE) ORDER BY ColumnOrder) DesiredNames
         ) rn

         IF @DesiredID = 0
         BEGIN
             PRINT @DesiredID
             PRINT @VALUE
         BREAK
     END

     SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names are different, you can do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = nn.cnt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as all_same
FROM Names n JOIN
     fn_GetColumns(@id) gc(name)
     ON n.name = gc.name CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM names) nn;
```

This counts the number of matches and compares it to the total number of names.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I've put your query into pseudo code section and gets the following error:  `Invalid Object Name 'fn_GetColumns'`. And one more question, please, how can I know id? And what do you mean by `Assuming the names are different`

Comment: @StepUp . . . `fn_getcolumns()` is your syntax, not mine.  SQL Server requires at least the schema for UDFs.  As for different names, that means that they are unique for each result set.